# Concealing IP address when sending via Gmail on another device

Tags: gmail, privacy, iphone, ip-address

Normally when you send an email via Gmail's web interface, your IP address is not revealed in the `Received:` headers. However, if you configure a device such as the iPhone to send mail via Gmail's SMTP server, your IP address will be revealed every time you send an email from that device.

Is there any way to configure the SMTP server in such a way that I can send email via Gmail's SMTP server on my device (in this case an iPhone), but still have my IP address concealed?

I'm not looking for an answer such as "use the web interface via the mobile browser". I'm looking for something that can use the native apps on my device (in this case iPhone's Mail app).

Comment: Haven't looked into it,but I'd have thought that this is a deliberate anti-spam measure by Google. They've got all sorts of ways of controlling your usage via the web interface, but if you're connecting directly to your SMTP servers it's probably easier for them to keep track of what IPs are doing what and block accordingly.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I would think that since it requires authentication to send via SMTP, they could still monitor abuse.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy: open a [proXPN](http://proXPN.com) account (free) and follow the [instructions on their support site](http://support.proxpn.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=15) on how to set up your iPhone. This will hide your real IP.

Comment: If I understand correctly how this works, this secures all network activity on the device by sending it encrypted to proXPN's servers, and then sends it unencrypted to Gmail's servers. As a side effect, Gmail will see that the email originated from proXPN's server and report that as the IP address instead of my device's IP address. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Sensful - you got it. And the IP changes each time you connect/disconnect